# how do i make operations on a specific line in a text file in c?

Tags: c

```
void main(void)
{
    FILE* textfile;
    char    line[1000];

    textfile = fopen("omar.txt", "r");
    if (textfile == NULL)
        return 1;

    while (fgets(line, 1000, textfile)) {
        printf(line);
    }

    fclose(textfile);
}
```

so this code prints the whole content of a text file , what should I do to read the third line in the file for example ?

Comment: How would you do something to the N'th item in a loop? Keep a counter, increment it on each iteration, and do whatever you need to do when you reach the N'th item.

Comment: Never write `printf(line);` unless you can be absolutely sure the contents of `line` are completely controlled by trusted parties or otherwise made safe. If an attacker can influence the contents of `line`, they may be able to use it to exploit your program. To write the contents of `line` to standard output, use `fputs(line, stdout);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the `nth` line in a file you can do something like this

```
int i = 0;

while (fgets(line, 1000, textfile)) { 
 
       i++;

       if (i == n) {
           // do stuff with nth line
           break;
       }
}
```

This approach uses a counter to count until the `nth` iteration is reached. Once it is, you can do what you need to do with the `nth` line.

Also this may be unrelated but you should never use `printf` without a format specifier as you have in `printf(line);`. This can be dangerous and could be used by an attacker to exploit the program. I would recommend that in your case `puts(line);` is a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
int readNthLine(FILE *fi, char *buff, size_t buffsize, size_t line)
{
    fseek(fi, 0, SEEK_SET);
    {
        for(size_t cline = 0; cline < line; cline++)
        {
            if(!fgets(buff, buffsize, fi)) return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This very simple function will work only if the size of the buffer is larger than the length of the longest line in the file.

Of course, you should check the result of any I/O operation.

Comment: what variable should I pass the number of the line to ?

Comment: @OmarA.Abdelazim: The parameter `line` should contain the line number.

Comment: Why DV? What is wrong?